# How to Execute UpdateAsync with Where statement

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I have a table with 1 row. log => 1 | flagLog => 0

```
 public async void updateFlag()
    {
        var local = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "hinos.sqlite");
        SQLiteAsyncConnection con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(local, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);

        var updateFlagLog = await con.FindAsync<logon>(u => u.log == 1);
        if (updateFlagLog != null)
        {
             await con.UpdateAsync(?????);
        // update logon set flagLog = 1 where log = 1;

        }
    }
```

I got the row with this comand

```
var updateFlagLog = await con.FindAsync<logon>(u => u.log == 1);
```

But i dont know how i use to update this row.

Comment: Did u try `updateFlagLog.flagLog = 1` and then simply `con.UpdateAsync(updateFlagLog)`?

Comment: @Rinecamo thx a lot man, run!! I tryed a lot of ways, but it is very simply haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you only have to pass the object you want to update.

```
    var updateFlagLog = await con.FindAsync<logon>(u => u.log == 1);
    if (updateFlagLog != null)
    {
         // TODO do the changes you need to updateFlagLog

         // Update the object
         await con.UpdateAsync(updateFlagLog);
    }
```

Comment: ohh man almost.. with you sugestion i got and error but i fixed with @Rinecamo sugestion.